# PHPAdmin database negative primary key

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am facing a problem with my phpadmin database. My primary key for a table got negative and I can't see where the problem lies. I set the primary key as INT 20, auto increment 1. The negative integer is not a small number

Comment: Is there a problem with negative primary keys? Unless you sort by keys to get a "kinda sorted by date" result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default MySQL stores your `INT(20)` as unsigned integer on 4 bytes: `INT(4)`. This means you have a range between `-2147483648` and `2147483647` and probably you're overflowing to negative values. Using `unsigned` gives you a range between `0` and `4294967295`. You should consider using BIGINT(8). See the [documentation on numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html) and how MySQL handles [overflow](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html)!

Comment: Whenever i put unsigned, the item (paper) will not be uploaded into the database. When i uncheck unsigned, the item (paper) can be uploaded. confused!